# What will happen if the initialization method's parameter does not get claimed in the class?

Tags: java, oop

Normally a Java class will be:

```
class A {
    String name;
    public A(String name_parameter) {
        this.name = name_parameter;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A aaa = new A("ok");
        System.out.println(aaa.name);  // >>> ok
    }

}
```

Where I first claim a `String name` in the class, then when initialize the instance, I assign the `this.name` to the `name_parameter`. So that the `instance.name` can be found, in this case is `"ok"`.

What if I create a class without the name, but still force a name parameter in the initialization method:

```
class A {

    public A(String name) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A aaa = new A("ok");  
    }

}
```

Obviously, `aaa.name` will not exist. But this code is still allowed to work, is this ever going to be useful? Is there any way I can get the `"ok"` if implemented this way?

Thanks,

Comment: Nope, if you don't save something, then it's gone once you leave the scope where it existed.

Comment: It's up to you to use the parameter. If you don't it's useless (except for some methods designed for inheritance).

Comment: Basically, nothing happens.  The parameter will probably be optimized away by the JVM.

Comment: *is this ever going to be useful?* - No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way for you to get "ok"

The way I would think of it in this scenario is to just treat it like a normal method. If you don't do anything in the method nothing will happen. There is no secret thing that happens implicitly in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

It's not going to be useful and there is no way for you to get the "ok" since you don't have any property assigned to your object "a". By the way, you can refer these links to better understand.
1) [oop principles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130282/best-way-to-explain-oop-principles)
2) [class and instance variables](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/293478/what-are-the-differences-between-class-variables-and-instance-variables-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

If implemented in this manner you could never get the “ok” String, as the constructor will not set it to any of the class’s fields.